# comment_moderation_subject is not working for me

Tags: comments

I am trying to change the comment email subject with help fo the following code. but its not working.

```
add_action( 'comment_moderation_subject', 'editing_comment_mail_subject', 10, 2); 

function editing_comment_mail_subject($subject, $comment_id ){
   global $posts;
   $comment = get_comment( $comment_id );
   $post    = get_post( $comment->comment_post_ID );

   $subject = sprintf( __( ' You have reply for the Support of "%s" ' ), $post->post_title ) ;
   return $subject; 
}
```

But still it receives the older subject when it notify email.

Comment: [comment_moderation_subject](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comment_moderation_subject/) is a filter the comment moderation email subject. So use `add_filter`

Comment: I tried that too.  but no hopes.

Comment: Have you check your option `moderation_notify` ? and check if any hook into `notify_moderator`

Comment: thank you. but i found the solution `comment_notification_subject`.  This is working fine. Actually that changing the header, when the comment moderated.